# Integrating Google Maps API with Facebook comment plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, facebook-comments

Okay there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546202/google-maps-api-facebook-comments) but it is still unsolved.

Is it possible to add Facebook comment feature in each infowindow? I want a different Facebook comment stream to appear in each infowindow once you click on the point on the map. I am currently giving it a try but if anyone knows how to do it, it would be helpful if you can offer some help!

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.073231,-41.865238),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                map = new
                    google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            myOptions);


        var locations = [
            ["Event",51.526902,-0.085588,"London, UK","Jan 23, 2012"],
            ["Event",34.083517,-118.389373,"Los Angeles, USA","Jan 25, 2012"],
            ["Event",40.716428,-73.966241,"New York, USA","Jan 30, 2012"],
            ["Event",40.723454,-73.986497,"Queens, USA","Jan 31, 2012"]
        ];

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
        {
            var iconImage, heading;

            switch(locations[i][0]) {
                case "Event":   
                    iconImage = "img/event.png";
                    heading = "<h2 class='event'><img src="+iconImage+" />" +locations[i][3]+"</h2>";
                    break;

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: iconImage,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, heading) {
                return function() {
                    markerContent = heading+"<p><b></b> "+ locations[i][4]+"</p>";
                    infowindow.setContent(markerContent);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i, heading));  // end marker click function
                }}; // end for loop     
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of creating unique info windows for each of your markers and assuring that the fb plugin inside each points to a valid unique url. If you're not using markers and allow users to click anywhere in the map, a latitude + longitude hash would probably solve.

If you have problems creating unique info windows, this might help: [google maps api multiple markers with info windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111993/google-maps-api-multiple-markers-with-info-windows)

Comment: I added the code and I think I have created unique info windows. My problem now is how and where to put the Facebook plugin and how to extract valid unique URLs.

Comment: To start, you can generate the html code for it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Then, you just have to put it somewhere in this line:
markerContent = heading+"<p><b></b> "+ locations[i][4]+"</p>";

Finally, you'll need a valid url for each marker, something like http://yousite.com/marker/marker_id.

You can create the pages for each marker or, if you have a big number, you can make your server treat the urls as valid ones even without creating the page (like we do with pretty urls).

Comment: Which code should I put in that line? This one '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="5" data-width="250"></div>'? It somehow doesn't recognize the div class though. I'm sorry but I'm REALLY new to Javascript, so I really need help step by step. :(

Comment: Exactly that code (of course, you have to change the data-href). In order for it to work, you also have to create an app and include the JS api in your code.
I made an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dtVh9/

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly! So... I guess the data-href field is where I should place the unique URLs? Do I somehow need to create a loop for the URLs...?

Comment: "I guess the data-href field is where I should place the unique URLs"
Yep.

You can use the for loop already in your code.